# SharePoint 2010 - Security Trimming issue with Quick launch

Tags: security-trimming, quick-launch

I am having some trouble with this Security Trimming feature that maybe you can help me out with. Even with the Security Trimming feature enabled,  those users with no access are still able see the link in the Quick Launch and I do not want them to. When the users click the link, they get the proper access denied message so presumably the permissions should be set correctly, I just need the link to be hidden within the Quick Launch menu to those users as well, any ideas?

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: I can not reproduce this situation. When users do not have permission on my servers, they do not see the links in the navigation. Please update the question or answer with more detail.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the answer, in order to make links within the Quick Launch only visible to those users or groups with the proper permissions, you need to set the Audience for that link by going to Site Actions --> Site Settings --> Navigation. Then go to the bottom where the Quick List items are, select the proper link, click edit, and set the audience to the user or group that should have permission to view that link.

-Adam

Comment: I upvoted this answer too quickly. After double checking, I do not find this to be true. Please check your permissions and your links. In my test, I removed permission from one list and one subsite. All links were properly trimmed, including links manually added to the top nav and side nav for the sites.

Comment: Any idea why we didn't have this function ? (we are using Microsoft SharePoint 2010 standard) Actions --> Site Settings --> **Navigation**

Comment: publishing feature must be enabled, so user profile services and up sync.

Comment: @TomResing you're both right. It depends on if the navigation item is a "Heading" or a "link". Headings are security trimmed, links aren't.

Answer (score 2):

If the links were added in manually, then yes, you'd need to do that.  If the navigation is ticked to include subsites, it should security trim them automatically.  Hand added URLs do not get removed unless you apply the aduiencing as you mentioned.

Comment: @Eric same comment for you. I don't find this to be true for maually added URLs. Without any audience setting, I can verify proper trimming of manual links to resources in the same site collection.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Heading" instead of "Link" and it will be security trimmed. I.E. in Navigation -> under current navigation -> the one with a folder icon will be security trimmed and the one with a world and paper clip won't.

Answer (score 0):

Security trimming for manually added Links in navigation menue is only working within the same sitecollection. This is usefull for a menue on a Portal site for a sub-sub-site. Audiences have a few disadvantages like

- sitecollectionadmingroup need to be in audience
- audience for SP group is no longer working when the Group is renamed
- not working for AD Groups